# Access Django model name from admin url pattern

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-2.2

Given an url like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/foo/bar/
```

How can I access the `bar` variable from the request, using the `request.resolver_match.kwargs` ?

What kwarg does the admin give too `bar`?

Tried different keys like `class`, `content_type`, `slug`, `model`, but none of them work.

**EDIT**:

It seems the correct kwarg is `model_name` which is returning `None`, however. I managed to extract the model name using:

`request.resolver_match.url_name.split('_')[1]`

But wondering if there is a more direct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be just the app label. If you're hitting that url, then you are in the `ModelAdmin`class. To access the app label (foo in the question example) from `ModelAdmin` you can do `self.model._meta.app_label`, so you shouldn't need to go through the request.

You can access the model (bar in question the example) in `ModelAdmin` with `self.model`.

The model name won't be directly in the `request` object unless you put it there. You can get it from the `request.path.strip('/').split('/')[-1]` or from `request.resolver_match.url_name.split('_')[1]`

Comment: Sorry...I will edit the question. It is not the `app_label`, I want the model inside the `app_label`

Comment: @drec4s Then it's just `self.model`

Comment: In your example `foo` is the app label, ,and `bar` is the model inside the app.

Comment: I want to access the `bar` variable from the request object, not inside the ModelAdmin object.

Comment: So that won't be on the request object if you haven't put it there. You can get it from the url, but it looks llke you have answered that yourself.